# click on a button inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to find an element which is a button and click on it in protractor but I'm getting an error element is not visible.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
<button type="button" name="dog1" class="dog1">&gt;</button>
<button type="button" name="dog2" class="dog2">&gt;</button>
<button type="button" name="dog3" class="dog3">&gt;</button>
<button type="button" name="dog4" class="dog4">&gt;</button>
</li>
```

When I use `ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('dog1')).click();`
I'm getting an error element is not visible.

I tried

```
var dog;

 dog = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('dog in dogs')).then(function(rows) {
  rows.forEach(function (row) {
    row.getText().then(function (rows) {
     console.log(rows);
    });
   });
 });
```

and I print the rows but I still cannot click on the nested element.

I use protractor Version 0.12.1
Any idea how to click on that nested element? Thank you

Comment: You can use $index in ng-repeat to get the row number. That would allow you to set a different name for each button if you have more than 1 row.

Comment: When I use rows[3].click(); the click event happens in the third li but not in the first button of the third li and that is what I want.

Comment: If you want the first button in the third li, you can use something like `ptor.findElement(By.css("li:nth-child(3)>button:nth-child(1)"))`

Comment: Thank you Richard. That's the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just use css grammar for this (as in Richards comment):

```
element(by.css('li:nth-child(3)>.my-class'));
```